# inserting more items with same id into hash in Redis

Tags: java, redis

I am working with redis and i'd like to insert more items with same id into my table.
This is my code in Java to insert items into sorted set and hash in Redis:

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");


    jedis.sadd("list"+customer,fur.getId());
    jedis.hset("list"+customer+fur.getId(),"name", fur.getName());
    jedis.hset("list"+customer+fur.getId(), "wood", fur.getWood());
    jedis.hset("list"+customer+fur.getId(), "prize", fur.getPric());
```

Then i'm getting them from Redis into my JTable:

```
p = jedis.smembers("tutorials"+customer);

for (String v : p) {
        String pom;
        pom = v;

model.addRow(new Object[]{jedis.hget("list"+customer+pom, "name"), 
                          jedis.hget("list"+customer+pom, "wood"), 
                          jedis.hget("list"+customer+pom, "prize")});
}
```

It's working, but when i want to add same item more times, it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do with with Multimap object offered by [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework. `RListMultimap` object allows duplicated values per key. Here is an example for your case:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
item1.id = 1;
item1.name = "somename1"
item1.wood = "somewood1"
item1.prize = 12;

Item item2 = new Item();
item2.id = 1;
item2.name = "somename2"
item2.wood = "somewood2"
item2.prize = 23;


RListMultimap<Long, Item> multimap = redisson.getListMultimap("list"+customer);

// both items uses same id = 1
multimap.add(item1.id, item1);
multimap.add(item2.id, item2);

// returns two items by id = 1
RList<Item> items = multimap.get(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's against the basic functionality of any key Value store. If you enter a new value to an Already existing key it will be replaced. Suppose take this case

you do Hset( "listkey+customer1","name","name1")
And then,
Hset( "listkey+customer1","name","name2")

Now the name of listkey+customer1 will be replaced with name2. A single key can't hold 2 different values.